# unexpected output in php algorythm

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a page where i can choose the hour to take a date with someone.

In my database i already have 3 dates for today as here :

at 9:00, 10:00 and 12:00 so these hours should not apear in the page.

But what i have is this :

9:30:00
9:30:00
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:00:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
11:30:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:00:00
14:00:00
14:00:00
14:00:00
...

I think there is an algorythm problem but i'm not shure there is the code :

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: calendrier
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
//

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'content' ); ?>>
        <main id="main" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'main' ); ?>>

            <?php
                do_action( 'generate_before_main_content' );
                if(!isset($_GET['mydate'])){
                    $today=getdate();
                    $_GET['mydate']=$today['year']."-".$today['mon']."-".$today['mday'];
                }
                echo "<p>Entrez une date :</br><form action=\"\" method=\"get\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"page_id\" value=\"21\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"myuser\" value=\"".$_GET['myuser']."\" ><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"myform\" value=\"".$_GET['myform']."\"><input type=\"date\" name=\"mydate\" /></p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modifier la date\" /></form>";

                $mydata = $wpdb->get_results(
                    $wpdb->prepare("
                        SELECT *
                        FROM cal
                        WHERE user_id = %s
                        AND date = %s
                    ",
                    $_GET['myuser'],
                    $_GET['mydate']
                    )
                );
                $disp = $wpdb->get_results(
                    $wpdb->prepare("
                        SELECT * from disponibility where user_id = %s and date = %s
                    ",
                    $_GET['myuser'],
                    $_GET['mydate']
                    )
                );
                $cat = $wpdb->get_row(
                    $wpdb->prepare("
                        SELECT * from cat where id = %s
                    ",
                    $_GET['myform']
                    )
                );
                echo "<h1>Calendrier ".$_GET['mydate']."</h1>";
                foreach($disp as $dispun){
                    $debut = $dispun->start; // start hour
                    $fin = $dispun->end; // end hour
                    $debut_parts = explode(":", $debut);
                    $fin_parts = explode(":", $fin);
                    $debut_parts[0] = intval($debut_parts[0]); // int start hour
                    $debut_parts[1] = intval($debut_parts[1]); // int start minutes
                    $debut_parts[2] = intval($debut_parts[2]); // int start seconds
                    $fin_parts[0] = intval($fin_parts[0]); // int end hour
                    $fin_parts[1] = intval($fin_parts[1]); // ...
                    $fin_parts[2] = intval($fin_parts[2]);

                    while($debut_parts[0] < $fin_parts[0] || ($debut_parts[0] == $fin_parts[0] && $debut_parts[1] < $fin_parts[1]) ){ // foreach half hour
                            if($mydata != null){ // if there is already an date recorded
                                foreach($mydata as $mydataun){ // foreach recorded date
                                    $itime = $mydataun->time;
                                    $jtime = explode(":", $itime);
                                    $jtime[0] = intval($jtime[0]);
                                    $jtime[1] = intval($jtime[1]);
                                    $jtime[2] = intval($jtime[2]);
                                    if(strval($jtime[0]).":".strval($jtime[1]).":".strval($jtime[2]) == strval($debut_parts[0]).":".strval($debut_parts[1]).":".strval($debut_parts[2])){
                                        if($debut_parts[1]== 0 && $mydataun->duration == 1){
                                            $debut_parts[1]+=30;
                                        }elseif($mydataun->duration == 1){
                                            $debut_parts[0]+=1;
                                            $debut_parts[1]=0;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        echo "<a href=\"https://someaddress/?page_id=24&mydate=".$_GET['mydate']."&myuser=".$_GET['myuser']."&myform=".$_GET['myform']."&mytime=".strval($debut_parts[0]).":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo  "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "\">".$debut_parts[0].":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "</a></br>";
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                echo "<a href=\"https://someaddress/?page_id=24&mydate=".$_GET['mydate']."&myuser=".$_GET['myuser']."&myform=".$_GET['myform']."&mytime=".strval($debut_parts[0]).":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo  "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "\">".$debut_parts[0].":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "</a></br>";
                            }
                                if($debut_parts[1]== 0){
                                    $debut_parts[1]+=30;
                                }else{
                                    $debut_parts[0]+=1;
                                    $debut_parts[1]=0;
                                }
                        }
                    }

                do_action( 'generate_after_main_content' );
            ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
    /**
     * generate_after_primary_content_area hook.
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    do_action( 'generate_after_primary_content_area' );

    generate_construct_sidebars();

get_footer();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"https://someaddress/?page_id=24&mydate=".$_GET['mydate']."&myuser=".$_GET['myuser']."&myform=".$_GET['myform']."&mytime=".strval($debut_parts[0]).":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo  "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "\">".$debut_parts[0].":";
                                        if($debut_parts[1]==0){
                                            echo "00:00";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "30:00";
                                        }
                                        echo "</a></br>";
```

Have to be at the end of while loop